# ClickOnce and application settings

Tags: configuration, clickonce

I have a ClickOnce deployed Windows Forms application that uses application settings for two key features: the database the user connects and whether they use replication services or connect to the main server. Those settings were changed for some, but not all, users after they installed the most recent update.

What can cause application settings to be changed and how can I prevent it from happening in the future? The only explanation I can come up with is that I published from a different workstation than I had in the past.

Comment: Are you using the .NET Settings class, or your own configuration system?

Comment: The .NET settings class.